# Detect Eddystone-URL directly from Chrome Browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ibeacon, eddystone

is there a client based javascript way to detect Eddystone-URL beacons directly from the Chrome browser in iOS?
I know Chrome has the widget for the today view wich works fine, but I need to detect new Eddystones without pulling down the notifcations window.
Say a user clicks on a link provided by the widget, gets redirected to the Chrome app, does stuff, walks around and gets in range from another beacon.
Right now he would have to pull down the tab again to receive the new URI. But I need some sort of notification from within the Browser.

I hope you get the idea.
Thanks in advance!
Cheers
p.

Comment: This is something that we've considered before.  I've created an issue [here](https://github.com/google/physical-web/issues/572).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not possible.  Understand that Chrome for iOS is just a thin app around the standard native iOS `UIWebView`, so there is nothing you can do in JavaScript that you cannot do in Safari.  And Apple does not implemented any JavaScript bindings to the `CoreBluetooth` APIs that would be needed to detect Eddystone-URL beacons.  The bottleneck is more of an iOS restriction than a Chrome browser one.

Note that this is not true for the Chrome browser on other platforms, notably ChromeOS, which does provide such JavaScript APIs.